# NSOperation crash in NSKeyValueNotifyObserver

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation, key-value-observing

Our app has had a crash since launch. We've fixed all the other big crashes, leaving us with just this one. Crashlytics reports the crash like so:

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.default-priority
EXC_BREAKPOINT UNKNOWN at 0x0000defe

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.root.default-priority
0  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x3894b620 _os_lock_corruption_abort + 18446744073709552000
1  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x3894b61f _OSSpinLockLockSlow$VARIANT$wfe + 98
2  Foundation                     0x2e9ad333 __NSOQSchedule + 50
3  Foundation                     0x2e90cfaf +[__NSOperationInternal _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:changeKind:oldValue:newValue:indexes:context:] + 1198
4  Foundation                     0x2e90ca0b NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 90
5  Foundation                     0x2e90c765 NSKeyValueDidChange + 344
6  Foundation                     0x2e90be61 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] + 508
7  Foundation                     0x2e9ad1f9 __103+[__NSOperationInternal _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:changeKind:oldValue:newValue:indexes:context:]_block_invoke + 108
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x3881e0c3 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x388237d9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 224
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x388239c5 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3894ddff _pthread_wqthread + 298
```

Things of note:

- The memory address is always 0x0000defe.
- It always happens on a background thread.
- `__NSOperationInternal` suggests this is an NSOperation bug.
- Our code doesn't show up anywhere in the stack trace for this thread.
- We're using NSOperations in a few places, including AFNetworking.
- The main thread is usually doing something, but usually not using any shared resources.
- I can't reproduce it in the debugger, so it may be a device-only bug.

I'd appreciate any ideas or insight into why this crash is happening.

Comment: This sounds to me like a jailbreak-specific crash. Are the devices reporting the crash jailbroken perchance?

Comment: @remus It's definitely not jailbreak-specific. It's got a very high occurrence and it's happened to friends that I know aren't jailbroken.

Comment: Hrmmmmm Was worth a shot!

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely multithread issue.

Just supposing:

It could be reason that function was started before and finished after next call:

```
[someObj removeObserver: self forKeyPath: @"xxx"];
```

Here description similar issue but for NSNotificationCenter:

http://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/nsnotificationcenter-is-threadsafe-not.html

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, lock corruption strongly suggests that something is trying to use a mutex inside a zombie object.  From what I've read, KVO and NSNotificationCenter should be used exclusively among objects that go away under strict programmatic control, i.e. where there's exactly one reference to the object and it either never goes nil or the code that would nil it out performs a controlled tear-down (invalidate) call first.  Anything else is risky.